# Is there any other option for on_delete other than models.CASCADE for a ForeignKey in Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

Why is the `on_delete` property of a ForeignKey in a Django model not default? That should be the case if there is no other option other than `models.CASCADE`. Is there any other option for the `on_delete` property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple builtin handlers for the [**`on_delete=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete). The documentation specifies:

> - **`CASCADE`** Cascade deletes. Django emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint `ON DELETE CASCADE` and also deletes the object
>   containing the `ForeignKey`. (…)
> - **`PROTECT`**: Prevent deletion of the referenced object by raising `ProtectedError`, a subclass of `django.db.IntegrityError`.
> - **`RESTRICT`**: Prevent deletion of the referenced object by raising `RestrictedError` (a subclass of `django.db.IntegrityError`). Unlike
>   `PROTECT`, deletion of the referenced object is allowed if it also
>   references a different object that is being deleted in the same
>   operation, but via a CASCADE relationship. (…)
> - **`SET_NULL`**: Set the `ForeignKey` `null`; this is only possible if `null` is `True`.
> - **`SET_DEFAULT`**: Set the `ForeignKey` to its default value; a `default` for the ForeignKey must be set.
> - **`SET(…)`**: Set the `ForeignKey` to the value passed to `SET()`, or if a callable is passed in, the result of calling it. (…)
> - **`DO_NOTHING`**: Take no action. If your database backend enforces referential integrity, this will cause an IntegrityError unless you
>   manually add an SQL `ON DELETE` constraint to the database field.

Furthermore you can also write your own handler for the `on_delete=…` parameter. For example in [*this article*](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/pattern/a-set-delete-handler-with-the-object-as-parameter.html), I discuss implementing a handler that is to some extent the same as a `SET(…)` but the callable it uses accepts as parameter the object that should be updated.

In the "early days", [django-1.8](/questions/tagged/django-1.8) and prior, you did not have to set an `on_delete=…` parameter: `CASCADE` was used as default value. But this makes it rather implicit what should happen in case the referenced object is removed, so later they made the parameter mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

Pulled these from djangos documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

They have code examples too.

The possible values for on_delete are found in django.db.models:

CASCADE
Cascade deletes. Django emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE and also deletes the object containing the ForeignKey.

Model.delete() isn’t called on related models, but the pre_delete and post_delete signals are sent for all deleted objects.

PROTECT
Prevent deletion of the referenced object by raising ProtectedError, a subclass of django.db.IntegrityError.

RESTRICT
Prevent deletion of the referenced object by raising RestrictedError (a subclass of django.db.IntegrityError). Unlike PROTECT, deletion of the referenced object is allowed if it also references a different object that is being deleted in the same operation, but via a CASCADE relationship.

SET_DEFAULT
Set the ForeignKey to its default value; a default for the ForeignKey must be set.

SET()
Set the ForeignKey to the value passed to SET(), or if a callable is passed in, the result of calling it. In most cases, passing a callable will be necessary to avoid executing queries at the time your models.py is imported:

DO_NOTHING
Take no action. If your database backend enforces referential integrity, this will cause an IntegrityError unless you manually add an SQL ON DELETE constraint to the database field.